# Basic Stock Questions

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets

Hi I'm new to stock trading and have a few questions:

1. If I put in $100 into a stock, the stock rises and I take out $120, do I only pay taxes on that extra $20?
2. If I put in $100 into a stock, can I write that off as a tax expense?
3. What is the best way to make your gains work for you? If I put in $100, and it goes to $120, that extra $20 isnt really working to get me more money. Would I have to get out that $120 and reinvest it somewhere else, or can I make gains automatically work for me. In other words, will my stock gains grow exponentially are just linearly?

Thanks!

Comment: Tax questions need a location

Comment: @BernhardDöbler while true, there are some universal generalities which only need gross caveats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I put in $100 into a stock, the stock rises and I take out $120, do I only pay taxes on that extra $20?

(You don't "put in" and "take out"; you **buy** and **sell**, just like any merchant at any local market.)

Typically, **yes**.  However, there are a myriad of exceptions (mainly, but not exclusively, to do with accounts specifically for retirement) around the world.

> If I put in $100 into a stock, can I write that off as a tax expense?

No, because it's **not an expense**.  That is because **you still have that much asset** (just in a different form).

> What is the best way to make your gains work for you? If I put in $100, and it goes to $120, that extra $20 isnt really working to get me more money. Would I have to get out that $120 and reinvest it somewhere else, or can I make gains automatically work for me. In other words, will my stock gains **grow** exponentially are just linearly?

Stock prices grow **or fall** in a completely non-mathematical manner; **they change** (there's a difference!) based on **market sentiment** regarding:

- the competence of the company,
- good/bad luck (COVID, for example),
- general economic forecast,
- competence of the competition,
- government and legal factors,
- **investor emotion** (Tesla, for example),
- market manipulation (like GameStop)
- others I'm not thinking of at the moment.

An exponential growth curve can be "fitted" over two prices, but it's truly a mathematical fiction.

One thing you did not mention is **dividends**.  This is a company *distributing* (hopefully) some of the company's profits back to the owners.  With a Dividend Reinvestment Plan (DRIP), more shares are automatically purchased for you on the open market.  An example: if you buy 100 shares now, in 10 years you might have 120 shares from dividend reinvesting. **That** is *exponential* growth.

Comment: Follow up to number 2. If you have a $100 of stock and it decreases in price to $80 and then you choose to sell you can write off the $20 capital loss in some situations.

Comment: Yes; since now your asset is worth less.